# How to install the XCode 4.5.1 in mac 10.7.4

Tags: iphone

Just i downloaded the XCode 4.5.1.And when i try to instal,i got error like "error-4960". My mac version is 10.7.4.So please tell me how can i install XCode 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download through the mac App Store? This is how Xcode should now be downloaded

Comment: If i do that one then my current version is update.But i don't need that one.I need to install another version.

Comment: I don't think you can have two installs of xcode running on the same machine unless you have multiple directories

Comment: I can install two xcodes in same mechine in different locations.